# I allocated pointers l and r using `calloc` and tried to deallocate using `free`

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, dynamic-programming, mergesort

Here is my code for merge sort with merge as a recursive function and functions merge and print to print the final array. I feel like the problem is only with deallocating 'r' in function merge, but I can't find a reason why this happens.

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

void merge(int *arr, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int n1 = mid-low+1, n2 = high-mid, *l, *r;
    l= (int*)calloc((n1+1),sizeof(int));
    r= (int*)calloc((n2+1),sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        *(l+i)= *(arr+low+i);
    for(int j=0; j<n2; j++)
        *(r+j) = *(arr+mid+1+j);
    *(l+n1)=INT_MAX;
    *(r+n2)=INT_MAX;
    int i=0, j=0, k=low;
    while(k<high)
    {
        if(*(l+i)<*(r+j))
            *(arr+ k++) = *(l+ i++);
        
        else
            *(arr+ k++) = *(r+ j++);
        
    }
    
    free(l);
    free(r);    
}   

void merge_sort(int* a,int low,int high)
{
    if(low<high)
    {
        int mid= (high+low)/2;
        merge_sort(a,low,mid);
        merge_sort(a,mid+1,high);
        merge(a,high,mid,low);
    }
}
        
void print_array(int *arr, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", *(arr+i));
}

void main()
{
    int *ar, n, cmp;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ar = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", ar+i);
    merge_sort(ar, 0, n-1);
    print_array(ar,n);
}
```

Here is my error.

```
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone explain why I got this error and a possible solution?

Comment: Something like `*(l+n1)` is usually spelled `l[n1]`. It would make your code much easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, do you actually feel confortable writing `*(array + index)` instead of `array[index]` ??? What is the reason of insisting in using that notation.  Your program becomes completely unreadable.  Worse, why do you use variable names with only one letter?  Have you heard about the badness of casting `malloc()` (and friends, like `calloc()`) ????

Answer (score 2):

```
merge(a,high,mid,low);
```

should be

```
merge(a,low,mid,high);
```

Otherwise you call `calloc` with negative values (that's why the abort - core dump)

And as pointed out by @FredLarson in comments, use array subscript notation `arr[x]` instead of `*(arr + x)`, your code is hard to read because of that.

Comment: Ayy thank you soo much mate it was a silly mistake and I  was just checking the merge function to optimize the error not the function call statement.